# Which design pattern follow for creating an android project in android studio IDE?

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns, mvvm, mvp

I found, There are various patterns used in Android component and framework like:

**Behavioral patterns:**

- Observer (e.g.Broadcast Receiver, RxAndroid)
- Command (e.g. EventBus)
- Model View Controller
- Model View Presenter
- Model View ViewModel (similar to the MVC pattern above)

**Creational patterns:**

- Builder (e.g. Notification, AlertDialog.Builder,)
- Dependency Injection (e.g. Dagger 2)
- Singleton (e.g.View Holder)

**Structural patterns:**

- Adapter (e.g. RecyclerView.Adapter)
- Facade (e.g. Retrofit,Media Frame)

Actually,

I am already used *MVP* and *MVVM* design pattern. But Don't know
**What is the name of the default design pattern of Android Studio Project?**

Comment: I think is completely dependent on your requirement, Every `patterns` is there for a reason it's upon us to read all and check which will be more suitable for our scenario.